# Way to extend generic types in JSDoc with TypeScript checkJs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

For example, I'd like to inherit from `Map<string, string>` in JavaScript with `checkJs: true`.

```
class MyMap extends Map {};
```

This treats `MyMap` as `Map<any, any>`. How can I do the TypeScript `extends Map<string, string>` in JSDoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, one can do:

```
/**
 * @augments {Map<string, string>}
 */
class MyMap extends Map {};
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
class TreeMap extends Map {
    /**
     * @returns {Map<string, TreeMap>}
     */
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }
}
```